# matlab : separation of time and data in one cell of csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file 'test.csv' as below, .

[image]

```
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.017
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.018
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.019
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.020
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.021
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.022
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.023
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.024
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.025
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.026
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.027
P.M. 8:32:06 -0.028
```

I would like to extract data in the file, like below.

```
-0.017
-0.018
-0.019
-0.020
-0.021
-0.022
-0.023
-0.024
-0.025
-0.026
-0.027
-0.028
```

I made a matlab code as below.

```
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('test.csv');

cData= char(raw);

dSize=size(cData);

M=dSize(1);

B=zeros(M,1);

for k=1:M;
   B(k)=str2num(cData(k,13:20));
end
```

It works, but I'd like to find a better way.

Could anyone give me a better way to extract the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work for me - it give me error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

for the loop.

So, I can't compare speed of your and my methods.
But I can give you a solution to avoid the loop and create not only `char` array but `double`. Look at this:

```
[num,txt]=xlsread('test.csv');
func = @(x) x(end-6 : end);
str2num ( cell2mat( cellfun(func,txt,'UniformOutput',false) ) )
```

This will always load last 6 symbols of each string and convert it to `double` array.
Hope it helps!